# How to refresh the Android list data?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView`. I have filled it with array of objects using the `ArrayAdapter`. All the data is coming from the backend. When I click on the list item, I will navigate to the details screen.

Scenario:

Manager has a list of leave requests raised by his/her reportees. When the manager selects the leave request, it will show the details of a particular leave request. In the details screen, Manager can approve/reject the leave. After approving/rejecting a particular leave request, the Manager has to navigate back to the list of leave requests. Now the approved/rejected leave request should not appear in the list.

Can anyone tell me how can I refresh the list upon the leave request approved/rejected.

Below is my adapter code:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmployeeLeaveHistory>
{
    private ArrayList<EmployeeLeaveHistory> leavesList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context,
            int leaveOverviewListItem,
            ArrayList<EmployeeLeaveHistory> empLeaveOverview) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(context, leaveOverviewListItem, empLeaveOverview);
        this.leavesList = new ArrayList<EmployeeLeaveHistory>();
        this.leavesList.addAll(empLeaveOverview);
    }
    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView status = null;
        //TextView reason = null;
        TextView startDate = null;
        TextView duration = null;
    }

    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.leave_overview_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.startDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLeaveRequestStartDate);
        holder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLeaveRequestDuration);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLeaveRequestStatus);

        final EmployeeLeaveHistory elh = leavesList.get(position);
        convertView.setTag(elh);

        if(elh != null)
        {
            elh.setListPosition(position);
            holder.startDate.setText(elh.getLeaveStartDate());
            holder.duration.setText(elh.getLeaveDuration());


holder.status.setText(elh.getLeaveStatus());
        }           

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your `Adapter`.

However, be sure about that you call this function on the `UI Thread` otherwise your `ListView` will not be refreshed.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    YourAdapter adapter = listview.getAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain me how to call the notifyDataSetChange() on UI thread. I don't have that much knowledge on android programming.

Comment: Hey, i have already added piece of code which runs on UI Thread.

Comment: Where I have to call this method.

Comment: I have posted my adapter also. Please help me.

Comment: Where did you set adapter to the `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the detail activity using `startActivityForResult()` you can:

Check for `RESULT_OK` in the list activity then re-query the database and update the adapter.

OR

return in the intent the id of the item to be removed from the list and remove it from the adapter yourself without querying the database

The first option is better if you have concurrent users who can approve/reject.
The second is better for performance.